# Find the number of $a,b$ such that $p\mid a^2+b^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is it possible to find the number of pairs $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $a^2+b^2=0$ where $p$ is a prime?

Comment: of course......

Comment: Um... just count them?

Comment: If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ then $i \in \Bbb{F}_p$ and $a^2+b^2 = (a+ib)(a-ib)$  thus $a^2+b^2=0$ iff $a= \pm ib$ which makes $2(p-1)+1$ solutions. If $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ then $i \in \Bbb{F}_{p^2},a^2+b^2= 0 \in \Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ implies $a= \pm ib$ so that $b \in \Bbb{F}_p^* \implies a \not \in \Bbb{F}_p$ which makes $1$ solution $a=b=0$

Comment: @reuns why is $i$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$? I was assuming that $\mathbb{F}_p=\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$.

Comment: $i = \sqrt{-1}$ it is in $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ because it is cyclic with generator $g$ so $i = \pm g^{(p-1)/4}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ (say $c^2=-1$), then for any $a\neq0$ there are exactly two $b$ such that $a^2+b^2=0$, namely $b=ac$ and $b=-ac$. This happens when $p\equiv 1\pmod4$.

If $-1$ is not a quadratic residue, then $0^2+0^2$ is the only solution. This happens when $p\equiv3\pmod4$.